# What do you call this profession in English

Tags: american-english, british-english

During any cattle market (afaik) there is a guy who makes note of who bought or sold what animals at what prices and who makes sure everybody sticks to the rules. The German word for this is "Marktaufseher" or "Marktvogt". I'm looking for the English term. Below is a picture of such a guy which I took in Ibri, Oman.

[image: Baladiyya of Ibri noting down a recently-made transaction]

Comment: Hmm, Google tells me that "vogt" in German means "bailiff" and "aufseher" means "warden". But I don't think "market bailiff/warden" is a title in English. Lemme google a little more.  ... The State of Minnesota has 23 livestock auction markets, and titles such individuals ["market managers"](https://www.bah.state.mn.us/livestock-auction-markets), but I don't know if that title is used more generally.

Comment: If he were in a brokerage or a securities firm, he would be called a *settlement officer*, as he assigns trades to firms or accounts. He might instead be called a *compliance officer* if he kept firms from trading against the rules, for example, if they trade more than their margin allowed. If he were in a gambling institution, he would be called a *bookie*, as he keeps track of the book (of bets) and settles afterwards. If he were on the sports playing field, he would be called a *referee*, especially in the aspect of ensuring that the rules were being followed.

Comment: Few of us have experience with cattle auctions. If this were livestock.SE someone could no doubt tell you in a heartbeat.

Comment: Searched for "jobs at cattle auctions" for inspiration, @Robusto.

Comment: I'd call that dude a **tallyman** http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tallyman -- if it were a banana auction.

Comment: There's a comment with one good and possible variant (**tallyman**) now, along two good answers (**livestock auditor** / **auditor** for the first and **auctioneer's clerk** / **rostrum clerk** for the second). What's the english.se way of dealing with that situation? Do you wait and hope for someone to unify these in a new answer that clearly distinguishes between these and then change the accepted answer? Do you try to do such a write-up yourself as the question author? Something else altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Livestock Auditor](https://www.usajobs.gov/GetJob/ViewDetails/414610200) keeps track of the transactions and ensures that everybody "sticks to the rules." An excerpt describes the job of the **Auditor**.

> The [Packers and Stockyards Act of 1921] Act requires that stockyard
> companies, auction markets, livestock market agencies, livestock
> dealers, meat packers, poultry processors, and live poultry dealers,
> whose operations are subject to the Act, maintain such records that
> will **disclose in detail all transactions** involved in their business
> including their true ownership.
> P&SP makes periodic and special examinations of reports and records of
> persons and firms subject to the Act in order
> **to ascertain whether they are operating in full compliance** with the Act.

(emphasis added)

Answer (score 2):

Auctioneer's Clerk or Rostrum Clerk

"the purchaser is required to hand to the Auctioneer's Clerk a note of his/her name and address"

http://www.sva-auctions.co.uk/html/Terms.html

"Records amounts of final bids for merchandise at auction sales, and receives money from final bidders at auction:"

https://dot-job-descriptions.careerplanner.com/AUCTION-CLERK.cfm

"Receive and record deposits and bids from customers in the auction hall and 'live on line’ as Company procedure dictates and to ensure all deposits and entry forms taken are processed in accordance with Company procedures."

https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/rostrum-clerk-60957/36646752

"Receive and record deposits and bids from customers in the auction hall and 'live on line’ as Company procedure dictates and to ensure all deposits and entry forms taken are processed in accordance with Company procedures."

https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/rostrum-clerk-60957/36646752

"Upon completion of our clerking and cashiering course, you will have a full understanding of how to successfully clerk and cashier any auction you conduct."

https://www.auctionschools.com/auction-clerk-cashier-training/